# Как в django сделать кнопку "читать далее >>"?

Tags: python, django

То есть кнопку "читать далее >>" я сделал и она даже функционирует как нужно, но в этой кнопке нет смысла так как мои посты отображаются в полном виде. Как установить ограничение на символы? вот эта строчка я думаю решающая в моём случае. но как и куда её применить я не знаю. Я лишь прописал её в *model.py*

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    # v--- вот эта строчка ---v
    slug = models.CharField(verbose_name='lasha', max_length=100,blank=True)

def get_abs_url(self):
    return '/blog/{0}/'.format(self.id)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модели тут не при чем. Модель - это средство взаимодействия с базой данных. Тебе нужно смотреть в сторону шаблонов. В частности при передачи контекста в шаблон обрезать контент, либо использовать в самом шаблоне фильтр truncatechars (truncatewords) с длинной текста в качестве аргумента.
См. здесь:
 http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/templates/builtins.html#truncatechars  http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/templates/builtins.html#truncatewords

Comment: Вообще можно и в модель добавить поле, содержащее текст перед кнопкой «Читать далее» (на многих сайтах видел подобное), но это уже по вкусу

Answer (score 1):

нужно сделать

1. context_processror чтобы передавать значения в шаблон
2. в шаблоне выводить полями
3. добавить кнопку читать далее со ссылкой на пост